# Why do we use form or ng-submit in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, forms, post, submit, ng-submit

I am planning to have an angularjs application. We will be doing the CRUD operation using Web Api service. And these controller functions I can call from ng-click directive (I mean with out a submit)

`AngularJs <-> WebApi <-> Sql Serevr` => This is our stack.

We need get call to web server (to fetch files. Ex: images).

But I am wondering, will we ever need a post operation into webserver in our case?

Also, do we ever need a form,ng-form,submit,ng-submit - in our case?

Any help would be apprecicated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of reasons outside of just submitting to use a `<form>` tag in your code.  For one, angular wires up validation results right into the form object.  If you didn't have the form, you wouldn't get that functionality.

I'd suggest taking a look at the example at the bottom of the Angular Form documentation to see why you may want to use the Form.  You can see how the form.$valid and form.$error change if you clear out the textbox in the example.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Regarding submitting, ngSubmit will prevent the default action of a form which is usually posting the server.  Similar to the validation properties that exist, there is also a `form.$submitted` property that will be updated to true when the form is submitted with an ng-submit.  This will not happen on an ng-click.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: The validation part I get. Other than that it seems...we don't do much with submit (My previous web experience is in asp.net- so am comparing with it).

Answer (score 0):

Not much different，but `ng-submit` would be prevent by `input[required]` etc. `ng-click` is unlimited