# why we use "NgForm" tag in angular

Tags: angular

why we must use "NgForm" in a form tag when this attribute is automatically attached to this tag?is this a typo? what is the benefit of using this tag?
and is that any way to use this tag without attaching directly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056405/why-do-we-use-form-or-ng-submit-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #frmstudent="ngForm">
```

Mentioning ngForm explicitly is optional. If not mentioned, angular will mention automatically.

The NgForm directive supplements the form element with additional features. It holds the controls you created for the elements with an ngModel directive and name attribute, and monitors their properties, including their validity. It also has its own validproperty which is true only if every contained controlis valid.